# How to check if array elements are the same

Tags: java, arrays, input

I'm trying to get 5 numbers by the users via console input and check if all elements of this arrays are the same. If so, it shall print "Kniffel!" (what's Yahtzee in Germany if you care to know). But I can't figure out how to check the actual input.

This is my code so far

```
public class Kniffel
{

    private static Scanner sc2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] numbers = new int[5];

        System.out.println("Gib " + numbers.length + " Zahlen getrennt von Leerzeichen ein: ");

        sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = sc2.nextInt();

        boolean flag = true;
        int first = numbers[0];

         for(int index = 1; index < numbers.length; index++){
                if (numbers[index] != first) flag = false;
            }
         if (flag) System.out.println("Kniffel!");


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0; i<=numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i] = sc2.nextInt();
}
```

This will iterate over the array and assign a number provided by the user input to each index of the array.

Comment: Consider including a brief explanation of how the above solve the problem, rather than just posting code.